# Cant see the UIActivityIndicatorView during Call to Server for data

Tags: ios, multithreading, http, nsthread, uiactivityindicatorview

I'm writing an app that is calling a server to get data to show to the user as the app starts, the call to the server is a sync call, i want to show the user a UIActivityIndicatorView, but i cant see it Although i'm activating the UIActivityIndicatorView in a new Thread, hear is the code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
    spinner.frame = CGRectMake(50, 50, 50, 50);

    [self.tableView addSubview:spinner];
    [self.tableView bringSubviewToFront:spinner];

    singeltoneData *sing = [singeltoneData sharedInstance]; 
    firstTimeSearch = YES;
    firstTimeSearchClick = YES;
    NSNumber *num = [[NSNumber alloc]initWithInt:-1];
    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(spin:) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
    [self getData:num];

    filterCalls = [[sing.globalCallsDitionary objectForKey:@"Calls"]mutableCopy];
    allCalls = [[sing.globalCallsDitionary objectForKey:@"Calls"]mutableCopy];
    callsDetails = [[sing.globalCallsDitionary objectForKey:@"CallDetails"]mutableCopy];
    filteredCallsDetails = [[sing.globalCallsDitionary objectForKey:@"CallDetails"]mutableCopy];

#if defined(__IPHONE_5_0) && __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= __IPHONE_5_0
    if ([self.navigationController.navigationBar respondsToSelector:@selector( setBackgroundImage:forBarMetrics:)]){
        [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"top.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    }
#endif

    [self buildBar];    
    woman = [UIImage imageNamed:@"woman.png"];

}
```

next my spin function looks like this

```
/************************************************************/
/*                 Spinner                                  */
/************************************************************/    
- (void) spin:(id)data{
    [spinner startAnimating];

}
```

I'm also calling it from refresh data call to the server:

```
- (void)activateActions:(id)sender {
    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(spin:) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
    singeltoneData *sing = [[singeltoneData sharedInstance]autorelease]; 

    [allCalls removeAllObjects];
    [callsDetails removeAllObjects];
    [filterCalls removeAllObjects];
    [filteredCallsDetails removeAllObjects];
    NSNumber *num = [[NSNumber alloc]initWithInt:-1];
    [self getData:num];
    filterCalls = [[sing.globalCallsDitionary objectForKey:@"Calls"]mutableCopy];
    filteredCallsDetails = [[sing.globalCallsDitionary objectForKey:@"CallDetails"]mutableCopy];
    allCalls = [[sing.globalCallsDitionary objectForKey:@"Calls"]mutableCopy];
    callsDetails = [[sing.globalCallsDitionary objectForKey:@"CallDetails"]mutableCopy];
    [self.tableView reloadData];  
}
```

still i dont see the spinner

any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(spin:) toTarget:self withObject:nil];

- (void) spin:(id)data{
    [spinner startAnimating];

}
```

Based on above you are animating the spinner on a different thread..but all UI update should be done on the main thread..so that might be the reason you don't see the activity animating